# xcode Can't exec "/usr/bin/svnversion"

Tags: xcode, macos

Since upgrading to Mac OS X Mountain Lion, "/usr/bin/svnversion" has gone missing. How can I resolve this error?

```
Can't exec "/usr/bin/svnversion": No such file or directory at /Users/realmasse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExamGame-gvcepttntbnapmeeeyndutgfakbn/Build/Intermediates/ExamGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HOE.build/Script-C428913C15B9011A0029ED43.sh line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $version in pattern match (m//) at /Users/realmasse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExamGame-gvcepttntbnapmeeeyndutgfakbn/Build/Intermediates/ExamGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HOE.build/Script-C428913C15B9011A0029ED43.sh line 29.
/Users/realmasse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExamGame-gvcepttntbnapmeeeyndutgfakbn/Build/Intermediates/ExamGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HOE.build/Script-C428913C15B9011A0029ED43.sh: No Subversion revision found at /Users/realmasse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExamGame-gvcepttntbnapmeeeyndutgfakbn/Build/Intermediates/ExamGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HOE.build/Script-C428913C15B9011A0029ED43.sh line 31.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest Xcode (version 4.5) installed as `/Applications/Xcode.app`.
2. In Xcode's Preferences, go to Downloads, then Components, and make sure the Command Line Tools are installed.
3. From the command line (e.g. in Terminal.app), run this: `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

Comment: thank you. i'm installing Command Line Tools.

Comment: Can I perform this command in a terminal? What is the difference between the terminal and command line tools?
sorry i am beginners.

Comment: ok solved.i installed just command Line Tools. thanks a lot :)